# Call VB.NET Sub After Function

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.NET subroutine which calls 2 functions and then another sub.  The first two functions in sub GetFirstLineGradeAndSecondLineUser() get called and return the values just fine but after the second function, GetRandomSecondLineUser, is called, the code doesn't continue and call the final sub AssignSecondLineRefund at all. I'm wondering if I'm structuring the code improperly or violating some basic fundamental way that VB works? Thanks

```
Sub GetFirstLineGradeAndSecondLineUser(ByVal RefundID As Integer, ByVal strFirstLineUserID As String)
    Dim strFirstLineGrade As String
    Dim strSecondLineUserID As String

    'First step is to get the first line users grade passing in FirstLineUserID
    strFirstLineGrade = GetFirstLineUserGrade(strFirstLineUserID)

    'Next assign the second line user name to this variable passing the first line user's grade value
    strSecondLineUserID = GetRandomSecondLineUser(strFirstLineGrade)

    'Now use the 2 values above to assign the second to the second line user
    AssignSecondLineRefund(RefundID, strSecondLineUserID)
End Sub

 Private Function GetFirstLineUserGrade(ByVal UserID As String) As String
    .....
    Return UserID
End Function

Private Function GetRandomSecondLineUser(ByVal Grade As String) As String
    ....
    Return UserID
End Function

Sub AssignSecondLineRefund(ByVal RefundID As Integer, ByVal strSecondLineUserID As String)
   'Subroutine here
End Sub
```

Comment: This all works fine. it must some of the code you aren't showing. put a break point on the first line of code in GetRandomSecondLineUser when the code stops at your break point put a second point on the next line and keep moving that second point down to the end to find out why your code isn't working

Comment: The only way that could possibly happen, as far as I can see, is if you are calling that first method from the `Load` event handler of a form and an exception is being thrown. In that case, the exception will be swallowed silently. You can add a `Try...Catch` block around the call to the first method to see if that is the case.

Comment: Show all your code, the code now as it stands would work... Show your function code, also turn `Option Strict On`...

Comment: I was getting an error message that I wasn't seeing and Try Catch block worked.  Thanks everyone.